# TextField getText() problem in ActionListener

Tags: javafx, actionlistener, textfield

I working in a console, and I want to convert the text to html format with color code. If I send the text from text field, I can't replace characters, and my text is doesn't get converted. Here is an example:

My test code:

```
WebViewConsole webViewConsole = new WebViewConsole();
        webViewConsole.appendText("§1This is a §l§2Test §r§1, just §l§2because§r§1!\n");

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setText("§1This is a §l§2Test §r§1, just §l§2because§r§1!\n");
        System.out.println(textField.getText().replaceAll("§", ""));
        System.out.println(textField.getText().contains("§"));

        Button button = new Button("Send");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                for (String htmlText : webViewConsole.getHtmlFormat(textField.getText())) {
                    System.out.println(htmlText);
                }
                String text = textField.getText();
                webViewConsole.appendText(textField.getText());
                System.out.println(text.replaceAll("§", ""));
                System.out.println(text.contains("§"));
            }
        });

        HBox hBox = new HBox(textField, button);

        VBox vBox = new VBox(webViewConsole.getConsole(), hBox);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox, 500, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
```

The screenshot:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egsz6.png)

The output(i sent the message once):

```
1This is a l2Test r1, just l2becauser1!
true
<span style="color:white;font-weight:normal"></span>
<span style="color:blue;font-weight:normal">This is a </span>
<span style="color:darkgreen;font-weight:bold">Test </span>
<span style="color:white;font-weight:normal"></span>
<span style="color:blue;font-weight:normal">, just </span>
<span style="color:darkgreen;font-weight:bold">because</span>
<span style="color:white;font-weight:normal"></span>
<span style="color:blue;font-weight:normal">!</span>
1This is a l2Test r1, just l2becauser1!
true
```

If the message contains that stange characters(screenshot), the text will be converted successfully.

Sorry for my bad english, thanks for help!

Comment: See if `WebVeiw` or `HTMLEditor` works for you.

Comment: I already use WebView for display the html, but my text with colorcode in textfield doesn't get formatted if I send it.

Comment: If I send §1Hello, and I want to replace all '§' character, I can't.

Comment: If you use WebView, you can use a js library color the text base on the language.